# How to run cutom for loops in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

recently started trying to do a bit of web scraping and i have run into a bit of a problem. Im trying to scrape pages in a custom order but i cant seem to get it working. Here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

results = []

for x in (3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12):

    response = requests.get(f"https://www.example.com/index.aspx?sign={x}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

#finds the right heading to grab
box = soup.find('h1').text
heading = box.split()[0]

#finds the right paragraph to grab
reading = soup.find_all('p')[0].text

results.append((heading, reading, datetime.now()))
```

So what i want it to do is grab pages in that order (3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12) and print the results, 3rd page first, 1st page second, 6th page third...etc. My code only prints out last result, page 12. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you haven't intented the code form soup = ... downwards. It's iterating over the correct url you specify but your output will only be the last 'response' that has been iterated in the for loop.

### Code Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

results = []

for x in (3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12):

    response = requests.get(f"https://www.example.com/index.aspx?sign={x}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    box = soup.find('h1').text
    heading = box.split()[0]
    reading = soup.find_all('p')[0].text
    results.append((heading, reading, datetime.now()))
```